# web part for list 

Tags: web-part, list, 2007

I can go to Edit > Add Web Part > Lists and Libraries > Pick a list "My Customer List" and wala it works.

The first column in the "My Customer List" is the Customer ID "Customer_00N" or so forth.

There is a single webpage for all the customers in the list. and the link to their web page is http://sitecoll/website/customer_00N/customer_00N.aspx

I need to be able to make sure the first column in the list is linked to respected customer page.

I am looking for code based solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you need a code based solution, but you could easily convert the web part to a dataview web part and change the first column to be a link with SharePoint Designer. This doesn't require any code, and could be done on a blank page that you create, then exported and imported to the page you want it stored on so that you don't customize (or un-ghost) the page.

Comment: Hi Lori, That will work for me. Wait, I dont have designer installed and it's they (team leads) discourages us to use SPD b/c it's does not keep redeployment in mind. I need to able to take this and re-launch it on Test and prod environment.

Comment: It is straight xslt if you want to code it and then package it in a solution package. Thats the only other thing I know of, or there are some 3rd party tools that let you build DVWPs without using SPD. Lightningtools.com has a web part that you can use for that.

Comment: Wait.... I am using 2007. I thought xslt is available in 2010.

Comment: dataview web parts uses xslt for rendering

Comment: You can always build the WP in a test environment and export the web part. Then import it in your production...